# Is it worth to include a "Publications" section of a CV if it only contains one publication?

Tags: publications, job-search, cv

I can't tell if this is trying to overrate my own publication, or that the achievement is worth "showboating" it to the degree that I've described in the title.

Comment: Depends on how you plan to use the CV. For example, it is definitely a plus to have a publication for graduate admissions.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is probably worth it. It makes it easy to find in a quick scan of the CV. Many of the readers will want to rely on getting essential information quickly.

If you are at the point in your career where one publication is good, or even exceptional, then, yes, single it out.

For admissions and hiring committees the first job is to take a pile of too-many applications and sort it into the "look further" and the "good bye" piles. You want to get in the first, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Every little bit counts in that area. Papers published in peer-reviewed acadeic journals, practitioner's journals, press articles, Revised-and-resubmitted papers, working papers, various reports, book chapters, are all welcome additions. I would like to stress that these days universities are getting more and more interested in "impact", so even small press columns or a magazine publication on an academic topic might impress and show that you and your research can reach and influence a wider audience.

What should not be included is predatory publications and obscure blog posts (although something in Vox.eu, Project Syndicate or a similarly reputable outlet is very welcome).